# How does the distribution of r distinct objects into n different boxes work?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

From my textbook, it says "The process of distributing r distinct objects into n different boxes is equivalent to putting the distinct objects in a row and stamping one of
the n different box names on each object."

What does it mean by "putting the distinct objects in a row and stamping one of
the n different box names on each object."?
Can anyone give me an example of what it means?

Comment: try doing it yourself to understand what it means

Comment: My English is not that great, I have problem understanding it

Comment: understanding this has nothing to do with english, it is a bad way of communicating, instead they should show the process by an example. dont waste time on understanding this, look for alternative explanations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us work on the case of $2$ distinct objects and $2$ distinct boxes.

First imagine a list of two distinct objects. (Order of objects matters in a list).

$\bigg(\underbrace{\text{Object }A  }_{\text{Box 1}}\text{ , } \underbrace{\text{Object }B  }_{\text{Box 2}} \bigg)$

In this case, we labelled Object $A$ with "Box $1$" and Object $B$ with "Box $2$".

This means that Object $A$ is placed in Box $1$ and Object $B$ is placed in Box $2$.

Now let us consider the next case,

$\bigg(\underbrace{\text{Object }A  }_{\text{Box 2}}\text{ , } \underbrace{\text{Object }B  }_{\text{Box 1}} \bigg)$

we labelled Object $A$ with "Box $2$" and Object $B$ with "Box $1$".

This means that Object $A$ is placed in Box $2$ and Object $B$ is placed in Box $1$.

Note that different people have different preference in the choice of words. I prefer to describe the process as "labelling" while the author of your textbook uses a more fancy (but unnecessary) description.

Comment: " .. stamping one of the different  $n$ box names .." is just "labelling" in fact

Comment: @GCab Yes, they have the same meaning. As I have mentioned, I prefer to describe it with one word, "labelling".